# Execute Immediate Statement issue - Variable field name and table name

Tags: oracle, plsql

Hi there I am trying to build a function to reset a sequence to synch with table ID's which have gotten out of synch with the sequence.  Function is as follows:

```
 create or replace
 FUNCTION P_FNC_SEQUENCERESET(sourceTable IN VARCHAR2, idField IN VARCHAR2, seqname VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER
 IS
 ln NUMBER;
 ib NUMBER;
 maxId NUMBER;
 newValue NUMBER;
 diffValue NUMBER;
 interimValue NUMBER;
 sqlStmt VARCHAR2(2000);

 BEGIN

 -- Get the maximum of the id field
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT MAX(' || idField || ') INTO ' || maxId || ' FROM ' || sourceTable;

 ...code continues...
```

My understanding of the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statement leads me to believe that this should be possible, however when executed I get this error:

> ORA-00936: missing expression
>   ORA-06512: at "PSALERT_ADMIN.P_FNC_SEQUENCERESET", line 16
>   ORA-06512: at line 11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would need to look something like this:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT ' || idField ||' FROM ' || sourceTable into maxid;
```

the keyword "into" is not part of the string that is dynamically executed, but it is part of the syntax of the "execute immediate" statement

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/executeimmediate_statement.htm

Comment: I missed out the SELECT Max(' ||  element from the original post.  But your answers is still spot on.  Much appreciated.

Comment: @PaulJohnson I copied the select from the question - could it be that the question was edited? Or else it was just to promote attentive reading ;-)